# JQuery-UI themeroller for version 1.8 or older - need to edit older theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have to edit an JQuery-UI version 1.8.16 theme but the themeroller only supports last two versions. Upgrading isn't a option for me. Is there a way to get older versions of themeroller?

Answer (score 0):

1) First, you can just edit the css directly.

2) If you want to try and edit the theme in the themeroller GUI, there might be a way. In your css file, do you see a line near the top saying "to view and modify this them, visit ..."? If so, the copy/paste that url into the browser and you should be able to edit your theme. The only reason that might not work is if you are using a version of jQuery older than 1.6. If that's the case, then I don't know that there's any way to edit the theme in the GUI.